# Compiling InfluxDB on Windows // Go Error :62: not enough arguments in call to conn.write

Tags: go, cmd, windows-7, influxdb, nosql

I'm trying to install the **V1.0.2** of **InfluxDB** on Windows.

I'm using the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34oOp1OLOUk

If i want to use `go get -u -f ./...` i get the error:

> github.com/influxdata/influxdb/services/collectd/test_client
>   services\collectd\test_client\client.go:62: not enough arguments in call to conn.Write

I have found this answer to the problem: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7251 and tried to install the 'gdm', but i get error :62: at the `go get ./...` command again.

I'm working with a **VM** using **Win 7 Professional SP1** and **Go 1.7.3**

Comment: Have you installed `gdm`. What happens if you execute `gdm restore`?

Comment: I think not. Because it says the `gdm` command is unknown. But i do not know another way to install it then the using `go get` and `go install`. @TheHippo

Comment: You probably need to add `$GOPATH/bin` to your `$PATH` (or whatever this is called on Windows.)

Comment: @Rico227 have you tried steps in the [InfluxDB contributing guide](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)? Also is there any reason that you need to build from source?

Comment: @MichaelDesa no i didn't try these steps. I will try them if i have time this week. I'm currently using the already compiled version wich works fine for me.